# GEQ in nested IF statements in batch script

Tags: windows

I want a variable to assign value from 1 to 5 at each GOTO statement. Below is my sample code, which is working fine-

```
@ECHO OFF

SET a=10
SET b=15
SET /A INDEX=1

:START

IF [%INDEX%] GEQ [6] (
    SET /A INDEX=1
)

ECHO %INDEX%

SET /A INDEX+=1

GOTO START
```

Output-
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1

However, after making nested IF statements it is not working as expected.  Below is the sample code-

```
@ECHO OFF

SET a=10
SET b=15
SET /A INDEX=1

:START

REM a and b are calculated dynamically, here for making the code easy, I am just assigning static values to them.
IF [%a%] LSS [%b%] (

    IF [%INDEX%] GEQ [6] (
        SET /A INDEX=1
    )

    ECHO %INDEX%

    SET /A INDEX+=1
)

GOTO START
```

Output-
1
2
3
4
5
6
2
3
4
5
6
2
3

Why 6 is getting printed? Since I am resetting Index to 1, whenever it is greater than or equal to 6. It should not print 6.

My aim is to get INDEX from 1 to 5, increatmented by 1 at each GOTO statement (EXACTALY SAME AS IN 1ST CODE).

Comment: "Why does this code not work as expected" questions aren't on topic on Code Review. Migrating to Stack Overflow.